# Why can we push_back a subvector defined only with range?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Say I have a `vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6}` and `vector<vector<int>>b` . Why can we write

`b.push_back({a.begin() + 1, a.begin() + 4});`

and end up with `b = {{2345}}`? I simplified this from a portion of code, so if this specific bunch of code doesn't work I will paste the actual code. I thought simplifying would help to understand the idea behind it.

Comment: Because the author of the STL has it designed in that way. What is the problem? The question?

Comment: ... and how you want to describe a subvector without giving the range?

Comment: Have you *tried* it? What happens when you do?

Comment: Why is this question closed? It is a very specific syntax with a very specific answer why it works (I mean, the given answer doesn't explain it well, but automatic casts could be explained here).

Comment: I mean, I'd like to see the language lawyer answer here, but the question is closed instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
b.push_back({a.begin() + 1, a.begin() + 4});
```

is equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int> c{a.begin() + 1, a.begin() + 4};
b.push_back(c);
```

This is simply calling the [`std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which accepts a pair of iterators and copies the values between those iterators into the new vector.

Comment: Naturally, `b.emplace_back(a.begin() + 1, a.begin() + 4);` is potentially more efficient.

Comment: @Deduplicator shouldn't make much if any difference, the vector in the original code is a temporary so should be moved anyway so it's only one move constructor you'd avoid using `emplace_back`